# JQL to get tickets from jira where neither there is a linkedTicket with specific summary nor a subtask with specific summary

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jql

I am trying to write a JQL where it can filter me the tickets of type bug or customer-task where there is not any subtask within it or a linked issue with specific summary within it

I have written a jql where I have validated that I am able to get

1. Tickets of specific type
2. Filtered by the ones that does not have linked ticket with specific summary

I am still not able to find a way to get further filtering those tickets with no subtasks or subtasks exist but not with specific title

Below is the JQL i tried

```
project = "abc AND (issuetype=BUG OR issueType='Priority Task') AND COMPONENT='ghj' AND assignee in ('mnc', 'pqt', 'hbc') AND (issueLinkType = EMPTY AND summary !~ "UT") AND issuetype = Subtask AND summary !~ "UAT"
```

Script runner is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in native JQL you can not achieve what you are asking, (which is pretty weird not having this basic possibility).

Here are tools that extends the functionality of JQL like [JQL-tricks-plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/31399/jql-tricks-plugin)

this plugin allow you execute this query (for your question) :

`type in (task, story) and jqlt.subtasks.count = 0 and summary ~ "whatever"`

Answer (score 0):

Jira does not provide a native way to check for subtasks. You will need to either use a plugin like Scriptrunner or write automation that populates and manages a numberOfSubtasks custom field. Your query would be simple.

```
numberOfSubtasks = 0
```

I cannot think of a practical way to filter on linked issues without a plugin.

---

If you had ScriptRunner you could filter for issues without subtasks using the following:

```
issueFunction not in hasSubtasks()
```

To filter out issues with linked issues with a specific summary, you could use

```
not ( issuefunction in linkedIssuesOf("summary ~ \"Search Text\""))
```

Your query would be something like

```
project = "ABC" AND 
(issuetype=BUG OR issueType='Priority Task') AND 
COMPONENT='ghj' AND 
assignee in ('mnc', 'pqt', 'hbc') AND 
issueFunction not in hasSubtasks()
not ( issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("summary ~ \"UT\""))
```